# Prove discontinuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

A function $f$ : $\mathbb R$  → $\mathbb R$ has the following two properties: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\frac{1}{n}) \to 1$ as $n \to + \infty$.

I need to prove directly from the $ε-δ$ definition of continuity and the $ε-N$ definition of convergence that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

The $ε-N$ definition of convergence:

A sequence of real numbers ($x$) is said to converge to a real number $a$ if for
every $ε > 0$ there is $N ∈$ $\mathbb N$ such that
for all $n ≥ N$ we have that $|x_n −a| < ε$.

How should I start? I also don't know how to combine the two definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If  $f$ is continuous at $0$, we have for any $\epsilon=1/4$, there exits $N_1$ such that for any $n>N_1$, there holds
$$|f(1/n)-f(0)|<\epsilon=1/4.$$

Now take $\epsilon'=1/2$, by the convergence of $f(1/n)$ to $1$, there must be an $N_2>N_1$ such that for any $n>N_2$, there holds that
$$f(1/n)>1-\epsilon'=1/2.$$

The two inequalities above contradict each other. So $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: I don't understand how you get this inequality f(1/n)>1−ϵ′=1/2. Can you please explain?

Comment: By your definition of $\epsilon-N$ convergence, since $f(1/n)\rightarrow 1$, for $\epsilon=1/2$, there exists $N$ such that for any $n>N$, it holds that $|f(1/n)-1|<\epsilon=1/2$, which implies $f(1/n)>1/2$.